# Android App to read write files in Google Drive

Tags: android, google-apps-script

I have a Google App Script web application through which users can accomplish the following tasks

1. Read/Write Spreadsheets in my G-Suite Drive
2. Read/Write CSV files in my G-Suite Drive
3. Read/Write Script, User and Document properties of the Project

The web app permission is set to execute as Me.

I intend to create an Android Application to achieve all the above tasks. Is it possible to build one? If yes please provide some pointers, sample codes or any tutorial to start with.

Comment: is it a google app script, android app, or android app running google apps script (not sure how your going to do that.)? If you are using just google apps scripts, how are you deploying it?

Comment: It is a Google Apps Script deployed as web app.

Comment: then why is it tagged android? your question contradicts itself saying, "I have a Google App Script web application" then saying "I intend to create an Android Application" which makes it hard to "provide some pointers, sample codes or any tutorial to start with" because they don't know what your looking for but i will answer with google app script because that's what you commented

Comment: also, please accept some of the edits, I'm sure they're probably pretty reasonable

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I already have a perfectly working apps script deployed as web app. What I need is an Android app to replace the apps script.

Comment: rip my answer :(

Comment: Edit: ok I can do this, try checking [google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) which is similar to google script documentation, except its in other languages, such as python, java, or node.js                        If this helps, accept my previous answer as how the question is currently written, it still pertains as a valid answer and anyone who views this will be looking for that sort of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some excellent resources:

> "Please provide some pointers"

I would recommend using this as a basis for all projects to be deployed as web apps, although this might be better suited to be a add on, I'm just going to go with it

1. make three more files (you start with one, code.gs, when you start) all html

   a) html, Index.html This is your main html code

   b) html, CSS.html This is your CSS (cascading style sheet) file

   c) html, javascript.html This is going to help you string them together
2. copy and past the following **removing what is there when you created the file**

code.gs

```js
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
.evaluate();
}
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <?!= include('css'); ?>
   </head>
   <body>


     <?!= include('javascript'); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

css.html

```css
<style>
 /* CSS reset */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
      html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
legend {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
</style>
```

javascript.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

> "Please provide some sample code"

You obviously have the code above, but try google apps documentation [here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) I prefer not to use this as a tutorial, accept for google app script only features. Its not my favorite but is your best bet for written code examples specific to google app script. Also remember you can always go to the `google-apps-script` tag in stack overflow too!

> "Please provide any tutorial to start with"

Most people would say [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/), and while I like w3 schools I recommend as a tutorial if you prefer to just google stuff to learn, not follow examples and try it out. If that's not you, I recommend you use w3 schools as a reference rather than a tutorial. As for a tutorial, I recommend [codecadamy](https://www.codecademy.com/) (the lessons are free, the quizzes and projects are not) as the number 1 tutorial.

Edit: Also check out [google app script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) for tutorials more specific for this question like [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I already have a perfectly working apps script deployed as web app similar to what is suggested in this answer. What I need is an Android app to replace the apps script.

Comment: ok I can do this, try checking [google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) which is similar to google script documentation, except its in other languages, such as python, java, or node.js If this helps, accept my previous answer as how the question is currently written, it still pertains as a valid answer and anyone who views this will be looking for that sort of thing